# how to restrict in inline jQgrid one column value should be less than 100

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am working on one application.In that I am using JqGrid but I am facing one issue is that In inline jqGrid having Discount percentage column the value should in that column must be less than 100 how to restrict that.Please give some suggestion on that.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most simple way would be to use validating rules. You should define in the column [editrules](http://trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editrules), which corresponds your requirements to the data in the column. For example

```
editrules: { number: true, maxValue: 100, minValue: 0 }
```

Comment: Actually I need also another option without click on save button how to restrict.it is possible on change event of that feild.

Comment: @Anuja: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. It's absolutely unclear which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). You should write **how you use inline editing** (call `editRow` directly, use `formatter: "actions"`, use `inlineNav` and so on) and with which options (for example `keys: true` allows to save by pressing Enter key)...

Comment: I am using Guriddo jqGrid JS - v5.0.0 and for inline editing right now i am using inlineNav

Comment: Actually in application I am using Inline jqGrid but there should be display only  one row I am not providing for that inlineNav that condition then how restrict column value less than 100.

Comment: @Anuja: I still not understand your current question. You asked "how to restrict in inline jQgrid one column value should be less than 100". `editrules` is builtin feature which allows you to do this. I don't understand your comment. Do you have **new question** about jqGrid or you have some problem with implementation of the restriction of the value?

Comment: yes this is my next question.I am trying your previous answer it works thank for that.

Comment: @Anuja: Accepting and Voting are very important for searching engine. You posed many questions. If you just accept all correct answers you will increase your reputation over 15 point and you will be able to vote up to 30 questions or answers **per day**. Everybody should use "accepting" and "voting" to help other visitors to find really helpful information on the stackoverflow.

Comment: :I am really sorry I am new to use stack overflow so that happened.

Comment: @Anuja: I understand it. Only because of that I described all so detailed. I recommend you to go though all your old questions and accept the answers, which solved your problem. After you will get the 15 reputation points you can review all the old answers and vote up all helpful answers additionally. You should vote up *all* helpful questions and answers which you find in the future on stackoverflow. In the way you help other people to find *really helpful* information.

Comment: Ok .Fine and Thank You so much for Suggestion.